# Laravel socket chat application

Tags: sockets, laravel

I'm new with web sockets, and i want to create a private chat with laravel between authenticated users and anonyme users , i'm not asking to give me the codes, i want a way to do that , i want to understand how can i do that

I'm thinking to that for a couples days ago, and i fount that i should make this steps :

1- Create chat with socket
2- intergrate it with laravel (1) 
3- show connected users ( i don't know id if that i should make that with socket or with laravel framework ) 
4- fix the chat to make it private ( build some socket or somethink like that)

i want to know how i can do that ?

Thakns

Comment: Please do NOT double-post questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create chat laravel application with socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677936/create-chat-laravel-application-with-socket)

Answer (score 1):

https://packagist.org/search/?q=socket

If I were doing this, I would separate the sockets server and the frontend implementation.

This would allow you to scale both the dispatch and the client services at different rates.

You can use any library of your choosing, usually the best is going to be on the top.

http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

That explains it a bit more than I am willing to.

basically you will have one instance of laravel that is only responsible for rest/socket communication. It will provide the client(frontend) with the information that it needs.

When a registered user logs in, You simply notify your socket server via rest a user has logged in, In turn your socket server will query the db for all currently logged in users, trigger the event of UserLoggedIn , attaching perhaps an array of logged in users which would then be broadcasted to all of the listening clients.

When a client receives that notification, your js (if necessary) would update the list of available chatters with the one provided by the dispatch.

You will also need to maintain a list of active unregistered user socket connections so that you know who's where and who should get what message.

This is the general idea behind it.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer , if i told you i'am begginer to do this , what steps you will give me to learn or to do it , to start working in this project ?
I don't know just give me any steps to do it !

Comment: If you are a beginner I would tell you to focus on less advanced processes.
There are years of learning in the above process.

You need 3 different disciplines (Laravel, Vue.js/Angular/MV? , Sockets/Node Server)

Laracasts has a number of relevant tutorials under the Vue.js section.